# 8-bit input in gnome-terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal, xterm

I'm trying to switch from `xterm` to `gnome-terminal` but having trouble with alt keys. I have already disabled menu access keys, but I still need 8-bit inputs. In xterm I can set 8-bit inputs in Xresources using;

```
xterm*eightBitInput  true
```

is it possible to set alt key to generate 8-bit inputs in gnome-terminal?

**edit:** it is also configurable using the option `meta sends escape` from `ctrl+left click` menu in xterm.

**edit2:** started using terminator, still need 8-bit inputs. infact, any libvte based terminal supporting 8-bit inputs I would be interested.

Comment: 8-bit input? All decent x11 programs hasn't problems with 8-bit input. Try to set locale to UTF8 before starting terminal.

Comment: I don't have any problem with `utf-8`, my problem is with the `alt` keys.

Comment: Still no answer? :(

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:eightBitInput)

```
   eightBitInput (class EightBitInput)
           If "true", Meta characters (a  single-byte  character  combined
           with  the  Meta  modifier key) input from the keyboard are pre-
           sented as a single character, modified according to the  eight-
           BitMeta  resource.   If  "false", Meta characters are converted
           into a two-character sequence with the  character  itself  pre-
           ceded by ESC.  The default is "true".
```

and the changelog ([patch #183](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_183)  2003/12/26):

> modify handling of `eightBitInput` resource in UTF-8 mode to translate the value into UTF-8. Otherwise an illegal UTF-8 code is sent to the application (report by Bram Moolenaar).

what OP is probably looking for is a convenient way to enter codes in the Latin-1 range (which coincide with the Unicode values).  VTE-based terminal emulators do not do that.  They use *compose sequences* for users without keyboards that supply special "national" characters.  (xterm supports compose also).

Further reading:

- [Gnome Cheat Sheet](http://software.clapper.org/cheat-sheets/gnome.html)
- [ComposeKey](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey)
- [How to type special characters in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux)

Comment: Enable eightBitInput will differentiate between Esc and Alt key (with 8-bit input turned off, both will be translated to `\e`). It is primarily not due to UTF-8 char insertion.